# Media Queries min-width VS max-width for responsive website

Tags: css

Since long time im using the below media queries to make responsive websites

```
// Large devices (desktops, less than 1200px)
 @media (max-width: 1199px) { ... }

 // Medium devices (tablets, less than 992px)
 @media (max-width: 991px) { ... }

 // Small devices (landscape phones, less than 768px)
 @media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

 // Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
 @media (max-width: 575px) { ... }
```

but when i checked bootsrap 4 , i notes they are using the below queries

```
/* Small. Above 34em (544px) */
 @media screen and (min-width: 34em) { ... }

 /* Medium. Above 48em (768px) */
 @media screen and (min-width: 48em) { ... }

 /* Large. Above 62em (992px) */
 @media screen and (min-width: 62em) { ... }

 /* Extra large. Above 75em (1200px) */
 @media screen and (min-width: 75em) { ... }
```

im wondering should i continue on my way or its better to follow bootsrap way ,
 and why they deside to start from small device to larg device?

Thank you

Comment: Do either way you want, Bootstrap is taking the "mobile first" approach with media queries, but doing them max instead of min isn't wrong, I do it all the time too. I think it's really a matter of preference, just make sure you use consistent widths for your media queries so you can quickly change all of them at once.

Comment: Bootstrap/Foundation go with "mobile first" which is what I also do as I find it easier to scale up than scale down. But there's no right or wrong way. Have a look at something like https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In its current form, your question is primarily opinion based.
It would have probably been better to ask if anyone knows what the reasons behind Bootstrap's approach might have been, although that question is, too, primarily opinion based. But your true chances of getting it answered are much higher here than trying to contact Bootstrap's authors.
And that's why I'll give you **my own reasoning**, coming from a hands-on approach: I need to get stuff done, it has to be fast and it has to be production ready.

---

As far as the ***order of `@media` queries*** goes, the only argument for using `mobile-first` over `desktop-first` is *it sounds better for people who have no clue what it means*. So you can always reply to your clients/boss, when they ask:

*— Is it "mobile-first"?*
*— Of course, we use the latest technology...*

But, in the real world, as long as your `@media` queries apply correct code to each responsiveness interval, you're *doing-it-**right***.

The only things you should worry about are, in this order, where possible:

- writing valid code
- writing cross-device/cross-browser code
- writing maintainable and easily readable code (for you **and** other devs)
- writing less code for same functionality.

---

With regard to ***using `em` vs `px`***, this is the second attempt by Bootstrap to dump `px` for `em` in `@media` queries. To my knowledge, the first attempt was dumped due to lack of support and differences in `em` calculation on a significant share of mobile browsers, at the time. However, a citation is needed here and I'm unable to find anything about that discussion which I remember reading ~2 years ago. I'm not even sure if it was around `v3` or the `v4` prototype, which was being released at the time. I think it was `v4`, though.
<strike>Anyway, if they decided to use `em` in v4, `em` is probably safe to use now.</strike>
**Edit:** Looking closer into [`v4 beta`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/milestone/41) — released just 9 days ago, it looks like what you quoted is from the `scss` file, later parsed into `px` queries into the final [`dist code`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L607). So I am assuming the discussion I remember reading is still valid today. In conclusion, I would advise against using `em` in your CSS `@media` queries.

---

Last, but not least, the ***`screen`*** part should only be considered when you need to take care of how your page looks printed vs how it looks on screen.

If you do need to take care of this, depending on the differences between the two, you have to assess the amount of code you would override if all your existing (`screen`) code applied to `print` vs writing all `print` code from scratch.

If first is faster, don't add `screen` to your queries and place the `@media print` overrides last.
If the latter is faster, wrap existing code inside `@media screen`, add `screen` to your existing queries, as Bootstrap does, and place your `print` code inside another `@media print`, so it doesn't affect `screen`.

**Note:** I prefer the first method, as it is a hands-on approach, easily testable and it usually results in less code being written.

Comment: I bet there is a performance reason to write mobile first media queries. So that the little devices, which we can reasonably think they have often less RAM than desktop ones, will have less rules to interpret, less css surcharges. Don't you think so ?

Comment: @Kojo, on the contrary. The technical aspects lead to the conclusion they should be the identical. If I was to put my money on anything, I'd bet the biggest challenge here is to come up with relevant test methods to back your statement up (or mine, for that matter).

Comment: My bad. I've just banging my head rewriting a whole site with that in mind. I think I read a post on medium.com about that !

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter which way you choose, as long you pick one. Both accomplish same thing, but in different approach. In `desktop-first` your "base" styles are for desktop/large screens and you make changes for smaller screens, whereas in `mobile-first` you write "base" styles for mobile/small screens and make changes for larger screens. Both are fine and you can use whichever method you think makes more sense.